# How to Checkout Files From TFS using C# Without Being dependent on Visual Studio Version?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have an application that generates some code files.  I have an option to checkout the files from TFS using this bit of code:

```
private void CheckoutFile(string fileName)
{
    var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(fileName);
    var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
    var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);

    workspace.PendEdit(fileName);
}
```

It works fine for me, and I have VS 2013 installed on my machine.  One of my co-workers only has VS 2012 and got the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What do I need to do to be able to make the checkout VS version independent?

### Update

Apparently my co-worker and had a misunderstanding.  He put the VS2013 dlls in the wrong folder.  Now that it's in the right folder, one of the methods calls in `CheckoutFile` is returning a `null`...  Not quite sure which yet.

Comment: After the update, the problem is different I suppose, can you please elaborate on the new problem, provide code if necessary?

Comment: @BeytanKurt I'm getting a null ref in the checkout file method. What other code would be helpful?

Comment: Sorry @Daryl, I thought it was a code issue but as MrHinsh pointed out, it is tfs version difference problem most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make calling the API version independent. You need to make sure that your users have the same version, or provide a certain of your app foreach.

You can however call out to tf.exe without a version dependant.

Comment: Is there a way to "ship" tf.exe with my exe?

Comment: afaik, it is shipped with Team Explorer. So if the client has VS or TE installed, you dont need to deliver it with your app externally. Otherwise, you can make TE a prerequisite install.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be pointing out that the project is missing an assembly reference or using statement but it might be that because it does not support some parts of the project. I would suggest either that your coworker start using Visual Studio Community or that you try to find a substitute for Services.Common.

If it is not that might you have a problem with the connection to the file you are referencing?

Comment: I'm not using a connection string.

Comment: Yes, I see now, well it is a file it is trying to find, if you want to be able to make it work, might my suggestion of substituting the using statement or assembly reference not help in that case? Is there a nuget package that is specific for your version of VS?

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, under project references, against the TFS libs, uncheck "specific version" and/or consider checking the "copy local" one.

Comment: hmm... it may be as simple as that... I'll have to test.